# Wearing a keepa in a casino

Tags: kippa-yarmulka, gambling

Would it be better to wear or not wear a keepa at a casino?

This is assuming the gambling is just recreational, and not directly with the intent to make money. Additionally, woul this even be allowed?

Comment: I'm not a Rabbi, but if going to the casino with the kippah on makes you uncomfortable, then you're clearly being conscientious of the kippah in a good way. It's supposed to keep us as Jews aware of who we are and what values we ought to represent. Don't let anything take that sense of awareness from you, and keep your kippah on your head, wherever you are!